# How can a segfault happen at runtime only because of linking unused modules?

Tags: gcc, fortran, gfortran

I get a segmentation fault from a memory allocation statement just because I have linked some unrelated procedures to the binary.

I have a very simple Fortran program:

```
program whatsoever
!USE payload_modules

double precision,allocatable:: Vmat(:,:,:)

allocate(Vmat(2,2,2))
Vmat=1
write(*,*) Vmat
deallocate (Vmat)
! some more lines of code using procedures from payload_module
end program whatsoever
```

Compiling this using `gfortran whatsoever.f95 -o whatsoever` leads to a program with the expected behaviour. Of course, this program is not made to print eight times `1.000` but to call the `payload_modules`, yet hidden in the comments. However, if I compile and link the program with the modules issuing

```
gfortran -c -g -fPIC -ffpe-trap=overflow -pedantic -fbounds-check \
    -fimplicit-none payload_module1.f90 payload_module2.f90 whatsever.f95

gcc -g -nostdlib -v -Wl,--verbose  -std=gnu99 -shared -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions \
    -Wl,-z,relro -o whatsoever whatsoever.o payload_module1.o payload_module2.o
```

the program `whatsoever` doesn't run any more. I get a segmentation fault at the allocate statement. I have not yet uncommented the lines related to the modules (however, uncommenting them leads to the same behaviour)!

I know that the payload modules' code is not buggy because I ran it before from `R` and wrapped this working code into a f90-module. There are no name collisions; nothing in the modules is called `Vmat`. There is only one other call to `allocate` in the modules. It never caused any trouble. There is still plenty of memory left. gdb didn't give me any hints expect a memory address.

How can linking routines that are actually not called crash a program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compiling your code with

```
gfortran whatsoever.f95 -o whatsoever
```

is working because you link against the system libraries, everything is in place. This would correspond to

```
gfortran whatsoever.f95 payload_module1.f90 payload_module2.f90 -o whatsoever
```

which would also work. The commands you used instead omit the system libraries, and the code fails at the first time you call a function from there (the allocation). You don't see that you are missing the libraries, because you create a shared object (which is typically linked against the libraries later on).

You chose to separate compiling the objects and linking them into an executable. Doing this for Fortran program using `gcc` you need to specify the Fortran libraries, so there's a `-lgfortran` missing.

I'm not sure about that particular choice of compile options... `-shared` is usually used for libraries, are you sure you want a shared binary (whatever that is)? 
With `-nostdlib` you tell the compiler not to link against the system libraries. You would then need to specify those libraries (which you don't).

For the main program `test.F90` and a module `payload.F90`, I run

```
gfortran -c -g -fPIC -ffpe-trap=overflow -pedantic -fbounds-check \
   -fimplicit-none payload.F90 test.F90

gcc -g -v -Wl,--verbose  -std=gnu99 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions \
   -Wl,-z,relro -lgfortran -o whatsoever test.o payload.o
```

This compiles and executes correctly.

It might be easier to use the advance options with `gfortran`:

```
gfortran -g -fPIC -ffpe-trap=overflow -pedantic -fbounds-check \
  -fimplicit-none -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro \
  payload.F90 test.F90 -o whatsoever
```

The result is the same.

Comment: Regarding "shared binaries", you can make executable shared libraries that can be run as normal programs e.g. `/lib/ld.so` or `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` which you can invoke directly to load and run some executable and its libraries.  Its a very specific use case though and most likely not what the OP is looking for (I'm guessing he was copying his build rules from making a .so for R to load without understanding entirely what the options do).

Comment: @casey Yeah, I know... But these would require `-fPIE`, which is not present in the command used by the OP.

Comment: Yes, I gave the shared library to `R`, so `R` was a mere wrapper that provided some input parameters. Now I changed my project to become a standalone binary getting the input from somewhere else. Now I see that I missed adapting so many compiler options that it would have been enough for a whole bunch of errors.